# Cisco WRVS440N Keeps restarting randomly

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable

I have a Cisco WRVS440N Router, it keeps restarting at random intervals usually we can get by for most of the day before it happens. The logs were not enabled so I have no data to work with until it happens again.

I had restored it to the factory settings and did a very basic setup to eliminate an improper setting but this did not solve the issue. Does anyone have any ideas what could cause it to restart like this?

I did notice that when I ran the cable diagnostic utility that on "Port 1" that we have a Canon MFC8300 connected to it said pair A and B were ok, pair C had a short and pair D was open. After switching to another cable (undetermined good cable) it came back as pair A and B were ok but now pair C and D had a short. I will make a new cable tomorrow morning to see if I can get the shorts to disappear, but I am wondering if this could be causing the issue of it restarting?

Comment: First guess: power supply.

Comment: Has the problem re-occurred?

Comment: No, after analyzing the circuit the equipment was on I discovered it was being overloaded. There were way to many items plugged into the same outlet I discovered it when the cleaning lady was vacuuming every time she turned on the vacuum the router would lose power although it did not trip the breaker it must have let the voltage drop just low enough to cause a disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

Without logs, any suggestions as to the source of your router's trouble would be pure speculation: not particularly helpful and rather unproductive.  On advising a next action, you're already well along..  Enable the logs...  Perhaps there may be some clues in them as to the trouble source before the next crash...

Ensure your software is up-to-date.

If you've a Cisco support contract, you might wish to open a case with the TAC, as they can alert you to any known issues with your particular product.  (I can't tell if this is an enterprise or SOHO device based on its feature-set, so this may not apply.)

For the wiring errors, ensure you're using the proper pin-outs, as a specific twist order are key to prevent cross-talk.  Use of [this standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568-B#Wiring) is highly recommended.